# data-callback is called after Google recaptcha is shown in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, recaptcha

Got some legacy to support. Details:

We have Google  recaptcha on our site which is normally called after form fields validation is checked in function defined with data-callback attr.

```
<form class="v_form" id="c-form">
    <div class="label erorr fullName-error" >Please enter your name</div>
    <input type="text" class="simple-input" name="fullName" placeholder="Full name..." required>

    <div class="label">Email*</div>
    <div class="label erorr email-error" >Please enter your e-mail</div>
    <input type="email" class="simple-input" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required>

    <button class="btn send g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="bla-bla" data-callback='onSubmitContact' data-size="invisible">Send!</button>
</form>
```

in JS:

```
function onSubmitContact(){
  ... //some input values validation, if not valid return false - else true;
return false;
}
```

It works well in Chrome - so if , for example, any field is empty - JS function return false and recaptcha is not even shown.
In IE11 - it anyway first shows recaptcha window, I select correct answer - and then it calls data-callback function. And then recaptcha crashes with error and stops working:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference
File: recaptcha__en.js, Line: 376, Column: 41
```

Can I somehow make it work correctly in IE like in Chrome?

Comment: try stopping the event? with the stop propagation

Comment: @Deckerz Since recaptcha defines when to call onSubmitContact function, I don't think calling event.preventDefault inside the function can change the recaptcha - callback sequence.

Comment: is there any update on this? a workaround? i'm having the same issue

Comment: @baryo Yes, I found workaround in my case. The answer will be below with details

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my question but with remark:
1. I decided to implement manual creation of google recaptcha on Load event.

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
...
<form>
<button class="btn send" id="submit_button">Send!</button>
<div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="<somekey>"
      data-callback="onSubmit"
      data-size="invisible">
</div>
</form>
...

<script>
function onLoad() {
    window.grecaptcha_id = window.grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {});
}

function onSubmit(response) { // recaptcha callback
    sendForm();
}

 $('#submit_button').on('click', function (e) {
var error = validateForm(); // validate function, if no error - false
if(error) {
//mark with red, no sending
} else {
grecaptcha.execute(grecaptcha_id);
})
    <script/>
```

2. So first I validate on Submit by myself and then, if succeeded - I run 
   grecaptcha.execute to start recaptcha check.

Remarks:

1. When to show pictures to choose in hidden captcha - google decides by itself. I cannot affect this.
2. grecaptcha.reset doesn't work. Whether I call it or not - anyway recaptcha sends uservalidate request to google and according to response decides about showing captcha.
3. nothing really was changed in app logic - just another way to call recaptcha - but now I have no error in IE11.